# FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.add() requires its first argument to be of type object, but it was: a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have defined my action in my PState interface, yet it still will not fetch my data. This works fine in regular javascript, but I am having trouble converting it to typescript. I do not know what is wrong with my IProps interface. Is there something wrong with my action?

```
export const addNote = (values) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    console.log('these are the values', values);
    const firestore = firebase.firestore();
    const notesRef = firestore.collection('notes');
    notesRef.add(values);
    dispatch({type: ADD_NOTE, payload: values});
  }
}

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { addNote } from './actions/noteAction';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


class Form extends Component<IProps, IState>{
  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      note: ''
    };
  }


  onSubmit(e: any){
    e.preventDefault()
    const noteData = {
      note: this.state.note
    }
    console.log(noteData);
    this.props.addNote(noteData);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
      <input
          name="note"
          placeholder="note"
          value={this.state.note}
          onChange={(e) => this.setState({note: e.target.value})}
        />
       <input type="submit"/>
      </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

interface IState {
  note: string
}

interface IProps{
  addNote: any
}


export default connect(null, addNote)(Form);
```

Comment: What line produce this error? I cannot see `getNotes` in your code

Comment: I just edited the error message my bad